# On the chemical weapons tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Earlier this year, I created the tags [chemical-weapons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-weapons) and [incendiary-weapons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incendiary-weapons). Later, a moderator absorbed the latter into the former. However, [napalm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napalm) and [thermite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermite) are **not** chemical weapons according to the common usage of the term.

Therefore, I propose that the tag [chemical-weapons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-weapons) be renamed. No good name occurs to me at the moment. [chemistry-in-war](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry-in-war) would be a possibility. Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Not "chemistry at war" :D

Answer (score 5):

I might have been the one combining these. The reason was probably that neither of the tags will have many questions, so I thought combining them would be a good choice; my naive perception was that the two are not so different. I would have called (wrongly) napalm a chemical weapon any time (today I learned...).

In any case, I support a renaming, while keeping the two in one tag (there are little over 10 questions now). Maybe 'weapons' would already be enough, it's a chemistry site after all.

Comment: I like [tag:weapons].